# Ionic how to create a datepicker

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello I'm new to Ionic and I'm trying to create a datepicker in an input field.Something like this:

[image]

I saw the docs from  Ionic framework but they have another form and doesn't work https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/

Comment: What do you have? What piece of your code is not working? What kind of form are you using?

Comment: I'm new to this,an example will helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a DateTime UI Component from Ionic. [Ionic DateTime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

**Template Usage example**

*Reactive Forms*

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm">
    <ion-datetime formControlName="signupDate"></ion-datetime>
</form>
```

*with ngModel*

```
<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="signupDate"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: Yes I have seen this but is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: See, you need to add more explanation what you are looking for. Your current question is too broad and doesn't really explain what you need, where you need it and what have you done so far that has not worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

using **ionic v5** & **v4**  you just need to use the below template:-

```
 <ion-item>
<ion-label>Date</ion-label>
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMMM YY, HH:mm a" min="2000" max="2025">
</ion-datetime>
```